# Spring Boot REST - error while updating

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

My problem is about that i can't update my entities. Everything else is working well but when i want update by patch/put spring boot is telling me there is no way to do that.

My user class

```
    package com.serwis.model;


    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
    import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import java.util.Set;


    @Entity
    @Table(name="User")
    public class User {

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Set<Post> posts;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Set<Photo> photos;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Set<BlockedUser> blockedUsers;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Set<ObservedUser> observedUsers;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="id")
        private Long id;

        @NotNull
        @Length(max = 11, min = 3)
        @Column(name="login")
        private String login;

        @JsonIgnore
        @NotNull
        @Length(max = 20, min = 4)
        @Column(name="password")
        private String password;

        @NotNull
        @Length(max = 25, min = 5)
        @Column(name="email")
        private String email;

        @Column(name="avatar")
        private byte[] avatar;


        public User(){}

        public User(String login, String password, String email) {
            this.login = login;
            this.password = password;
            this.email = email;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", login='" + login + '\'' +
                    ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                    ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public Set<BlockedUser> getBlockedUsers() {
            return blockedUsers;
        }

        public void setBlockedUsers(Set<BlockedUser> blockedUsers) {
            this.blockedUsers = blockedUsers;
        }

        public Set<ObservedUser> getObservedUsers() {
            return observedUsers;
        }

        public void setObservedUsers(Set<ObservedUser> observedUsers) {
            this.observedUsers = observedUsers;
        }

        public String getLogin() {
            return login;
        }

        public void setLogin(String login) {
            this.login = login;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public byte[] getAvatar() {
            return avatar;
        }

        public void setAvatar(byte[] avatar) {
            this.avatar = avatar;
        }



public Set<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

    public void setPosts(Set<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Photo> getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }

    public void setPhotos(Set<Photo> photos) {
        this.photos = photos;
    }
}
```

My userController class

```
package com.serwis.controller;

import com.serwis.model.User;
import com.serwis.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RequestMapping("/user")
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @RequestMapping(value = "create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public User create(String email, String login, String password) {
        User user = new User(login, password, email);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/findall")
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
    public Iterable<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "delete", method = RequestMethod.DELETE) //delete?id=4
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String delete(Long id) {
        userRepository.delete(id);
        return "Succesful deleted";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "update", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public User update(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

My UserRepository

```
package com.serwis.repository;

import com.serwis.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{
}
```

Error from postman when i'm trying patch/put with id=1 and login=loginn

```
{
  "timestamp": 1471783909628,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException",
  "message": "Validation failed for classes [com.serwis.model.User] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]\nList of constraint violations:[\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=password, rootBeanClass=class com.serwis.model.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=email, rootBeanClass=class com.serwis.model.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=login, rootBeanClass=class com.serwis.model.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}\n]",
  "path": "/user/update/"
}
```

Error from console:

```
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=password, rootBeanClass=class com.serwis.model.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=email, rootBeanClass=class com.serwis.model.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=login, rootBeanClass=class com.serwis.model.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]] with root cause

javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.serwis.model.User] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=password, rootBeanClass=class com.serwis.model.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=email, rootBeanClass=class com.serwis.model.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=login, rootBeanClass=class com.serwis.model.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344) ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:294) ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:439) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.serwis.controller.UserController.update(UserController.java:45) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:840) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
```

Save, find, delete everything works. My idea was that i can just find user, edit him and save but there must be better idea.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the login, password, and email fields are null when you get to the userRepository.save() call. Could you show the actual HTTP request you're sending from Postman?

Just curious, did you consider using spring-data-rest and having it automagically create the REST interface? You wouldn't need to write your own controller then.

Comment: when i'm updating entity do i need give all columns? I'm only sending one column with e.g login=logiin: http://i.imgur.com/Mm7CltC.png

Comment: If you're wanting to do an update, you either need to post the complete user object (including the id) so it knows which record to update, or put logic in your controller to first find the correct record, then replace the fields in the found object with the ones from the request, then save. With only

Comment: so how i can do that user should only be able to update email/password and nothing else?

Comment: sorry, that last comment ended abruptly when I hit enter too soon and then got distracted.

If you want to only allow those fields to be changed, I'd create a method that 
1. accepts id, email, and password
2. does `User user = userRepository.find(id)` to get the existing object
3. sets the email and password 
4. does `userRepository.save(user)`

Comment: Oh, and I certainly hope your client is not POSTing those passwords unencrypted!